# Is there a way to install JSX syntax highlights/syles for Notepad++?

Tags: reactjs, notepad++, jsx, babeljs

I'm using Notepad++ and I just started to learn React js and the JSX syntax extension but not having the styling makes it difficult to read. I'm not sure If I could implement the styles into Notepad++ or even if it's possible to import a JSX pre-processor or plugin. I was looking into installing Babel but I would also have to install NPM and Node js ect. and I'm not sure if that would be the best approach. Or is there a different IDE I should be using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to find the answer to my own problem. I was viewing the code in the html language because the js was included in a .html file. When I switch the language to Javascript the styles looked perfectly fine. The first `<h2>` tag in JSX threw off the rest of the code styles. Beginner's mistake.

Comment: How did you do this? I have a .jsx file hopen here in Notepad++, but all text is plain grey, no syntax highlighting applied. ...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann You probably already figured this out, but for others: Choose Language from the top menu, highlight "J", and select JavaScript from the submenu.